# Gain of a circiut

Tags: gain

I have been asked this question:

> Identify the gain of the sensor circuit.

If the gain is \$\dfrac{V_{out}}{V_{in}}\$, then won't the gain be dependent of the thermometer's resistance?

At 0°C, the output is 5V so, is gain given by \$\dfrac{5(V_{out})}{5(V_{in})} = 1\$? Does this question have a single answer or many?

[image: Circuit schematics]

Comment: For this problem, it may be important to remember that there is no universal definition for Gain (more on that [here](http://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/51069/what-is-gain-a-measurement-of-in-electronics)).  You may have to write your own definition.

Comment: You wrote "If the gain is \$V_{out}/V_{in}\$, ..."  Well, let's run with that for a little bit.  What's \$V_{in}\$ in your circuit?

Comment: The gain doesn't depend on the thermometer's resistance. The voltage at the top of the thermometer is almost certainly the input quantity that is being amplified: that is what is subject to gain.  If the input signal came in at the top of the 5K resistor, then the thermistor would attenuate the level in a variable way and contribute to the overall gain. What we have at the top is a 5V reference, and the thermistor produces a measurement signal.

Comment: OA gain is 2 but 0V reference means out = 5V when Rth=5k @ 0'C thus at 25'C Rth ~ 5k/3 for type with B25/50=3900, so result is nonlinear but approx 2.5V @25'C thus gain of sensor= -10deg/V

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Gain is  V_IC_right_out /  IC_left_+

There is a single answer.

Gain is provided by IC_left.
Opamp operates so as to maintain IC_ib_+ = IC_in_i
To do this IC output is fed back to input "correctively).
If Vout is scaled or divided down when it is fed back then required output needs to be higher to achieve balance.
The divide ratio above is the inverse of the gain.

Read above repeatedly while studying diagram until it makes sense.

---

Use locations shown below for Vin and Vout.

Also, what are the voltages at Vx, Vy, Vz relative to Vout?
What do you conclude about the gain of Opamp_right

[image]

Comment: Also, for the future, it's probably better to think of gain as \$ \frac {\Delta V_{OUT}}{\Delta V_{IN}}\$.

Answer (score 1):

Come on people. This is a standard non-inverting amplifier. Am I missing something? $$Vout=Vin\left( 1+\frac{Rf}{Rg} \right)=Vin\left( 1+\frac{10}{10} \right)=2Vin$$
The second op-amp, the voltage follower, has no affect on gain.

Comment: All you missed was, showing him how to find the solution, rather than handing him the answer.

Comment: There is a policy against working homework questions. The OP had reasoned a gain of 1, which was obviously wrong. The non-inverting amplifier is in thousands of books. In this case probably in the same chapter as the question.